# How to allow write rights only to specific users building a new module in OpenErp?

Tags: module, many-to-many, odoo, access-rights

I'm new to OpenErp and I'm trying to undestand access rights writing a new module.
Let's say I have  this module called Project, with title, description and a many2many relation with res.users called admin_ids, this relation represents project admins.

How can I give write rights on projects only to their admins?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

http://doc.openerp.com/trunk/developers/server/04_security/#access-rights

[OpenERP 7 Access Rights for User Roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15966676/openerp-7-access-rights-for-user-roles/15967895#15967895)

Here are the some links which helpful to you

you have to make a group and assing this group access right to write and give this group to uses